# Failed GRUB after 10.04 to 12.04 upgrade in system with LVM

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, lvm, grubrescue, boot-repair

I am using Ubuntu Server as a SMB server at work and two days ago I have tried to upgrade it to 12.04.

After reboot, I got this

```
grub_xput missing
grub rescue>
```

and all attempts to start from this prompt failed (missing components, although grub directory is normally set as prefix).

My system sits and boots on an LVM (soft raid-5).

I have read almost all posts in many forums, tried `grub rescue`, `boot-repair`, `ubuntu-secure-remix` with `boot-repair` but without positive result.

[**This**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1258899/) is the log of my last (and best so far) attempt to fix this system.

Any suggestions? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

The space before your first partitions is 32.3kB (63 Sectors x 512bytes), which is not enough for GRUB2. You are affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1059827

**Solution:**

1. Either increase this space via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) from 32.3kB to 1049kB for example, for all your disks (sda, sdb,...). Then use Boot-Repair to reinstall GRUB2 in the MBR of `all your disks`.
2. OR use `Boot-Repair --> Advanced options --> GRUB options --> GRUB Legacy`. This will probably work (because GRUB Legacy needs less space), but i don't recommend it because GRUB Legacy is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! For Nr. 2 solution, I will try it as last resort. For Nr.1, GParted does not (yet) work with LVM. Is there another tool I can use to move the partitions, which supports LVM? Dare I ask for a GUI tool?

Answer (score 0):

And to complete Solution 1, GParted can also be found as a Live CD
http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

(because, you know, LVM and RAID are only on alternate Ubuntu Boot CD, and Gparted is graphical which means desktop Boot CD...)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.